# Bash: Determining if CANbus Bitrate is Configured Properly

Tags: bash, linux-kernel, network-interface, embedded

I'm working on an embedded Linux (4.1.15) bash script wherein the bitrate of a CANbus may be one of several possibilities.  When my module comes online it comes up at the first bitrate in the list, checks for traffic, and, if no traffic, cycles through each bitrate in like manner until traffic is detected.

My initial approach was to do something like `timeout -t 1 output=$(candump can0)`.  If output is empty, then bitrate is incorrect.  However, the `timeout` function doesn't seem to force a return from the command.

My second approach was to try to do something with `ip -details -statistics link show can0`.  While this does produce some meaningful information in a single, discrete command, it's not very useful without being able to reset the statistics.

The command `uname -rms` yields this version info about the system: `Linux 4.1.15 armv7l`

If anyone knows how to get either of these approaches to work, that'd be great, or if you know another way, I'm all ears.  Bottom line is, I need to find a way to do this using bash script.

Comment: @meuh That seemed to do the trick, thanks!  I had to use the explicit `-t` for `output=$(timeout -t 1 candump can0)`.  Post your answer, and I'll accept. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(My timeout command doesn't use `-t`, but there seem to be different versions). By putting the timeout part inside the `$()`, it should be able to signal the `canbus` command, and at least the assignment to `output` should always create the variable.

```
output=$(timeout -t 1 candump can0)
```